# Rails method works in console but not through browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wget, delayed-job

Here's what I do in my model:

```
:after_save after_save

def after_save
    self.delay.do_thing
end

def do_thing
    Dir.mkdir("#{Rails.root}/my/path")
    system("cd #{Rails.root}/my/path && wget -with-some-flags")
end
```

This works flawlessly in development. However, in production, nothing happens. No errors, just nothing.

I've checked several things like:

- Sending the command to a log before it's run to make sure it's actually built correctly
- Running the command manually to check it's working
- Opening up a production Rails shell and doing the `myobject.do_thing`, which also works!
- Switching between back ticks and the `system()` command, to check if it was something to do with subshells
- Adding absolute command paths, like `/usr/bin/wget` instead, which also works in a command line but not in the web browser.
- Checked the permissions of the folder it's saving to

I know the `do_thing` method is running because it also creates a folder in the process of doing `thing`, which does appear in the filesystem, just not the result of the wget.

I'm genuinely stumped here. Any ideas?

Comment: which part exactly isn't happening that should be happening? Your post doesn't make that clear.

Comment: The directory is being created, but the command is not being executed.